# Send 2 sets of data via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im using ajax to send an image array:

```
data: ctx.imageDataArray
```

My question is, how can I also send the form data through:

```
$("#content-add-form").serialize(),
```

This does not seem to work:

```
data: ctx.imageDataArray + $("#content-add-form").serialize(),
```

Comment: What about it doesn't seem to work? What happens?

Comment: Create an object with 2 params. Assign each of those values to that object. Pass the object through. You could also have an array of values and pass it through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than appending the form data to the string, make it an object:

```
data: {
    imageDataArray: ctx.imageDataArray,
    formData: $("#content-add-form").serialize()
}
```